# Dynamically create and delete JavaScript associative array key and values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, associative-array

I'm using jQuery 1.6

I'm not so good on JavaScript and I need to dynamically create an array having 2 dynamic parameters: `json.id` and `json.name`.

the array creation should result in :

```
[

[json.id]
         [ 
           json.name,
             json.name,
              json.name,
                etc .....
         ]
[json.id]
          [
           json.name, 
             json.name,
               json.name,
                  etc ....
         ]
etc ...
]
```

Then I need to be able to delete a `json.id` or a `json.id json.name` ....

Is there anyone can show me how to do this with all browser's support?

thx
[EDITED]

the logic is this: (hoping it's clear :P )

```
    //first ajax call result:
    [{json.id_parent:json.name,json.id_parent:json.name,json.id_parent:json.name, etc..}]

    //second ajax call results passing the json.id_parent:
    [{json.id_parent_child:json.name,json.id_parent_child:json.name,json.id_parent_child:json.name,etc...}]
    //now for each call = id_parent create an associative array: 

{ 
id_parent:{id_parent_child,id_parent_child,etc ....},
id_parent:{id_parent_child,id_parent_child,etc ....},
etc...
}
```

Comment: Where will the data come from that you're using to create this array?

Comment: the data come from a json ajax result , for each ajax request i have many different json.id, then for each json.id there is a new ajax call which retrieves many different json.name related to that json.id

Comment: I am sorry, in your edit, did you mentionned REAL datas ? all I see is a data pattern, it is hard to understand what you try to parse...please type one typical data line (with some real properties and real values) for both ajax responses...

Comment: response should be like : "result":{"id0":{"name":"A"},"id1":{"name":"B"},...}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var myJson = {'id39':{'name':'Jesus','age':33}};
    var idDel = 'id39';
    delete myJson[idDel];// delete the complete reference with id
    var propDel = 'name';
    delete myJson[idDel][propDel];// delete only the property 'name' of the reference with id
// parsing complete json
    $.each(myJson, function(key, obj){// parse objects
      if(condition){
        delete myJson[key];// delete reference
      }
      $.each(obj, function(propName, val){// parse properties
        if(condition){
          delete obj[propName];// delete property
        }
      }
    });
```

Note, this sample assume you used json objects instead arrays so it is much easier and faster to remove sub objects or properties...

Comment: can't understand this var myJson = {'id39':{'name':'Jesus','age':33}};   i have no static params

Comment: that i need to create dinamically :)

Comment: so please write down a simple json data sample you would retrieve

Comment: the example you posted is ok :) just this var myJson = {'id39':{'name':'Jesus','age':33}};  can't be static for me ... i need to create that dinamically and away we go :)

Comment: yes but I am not sure to understand, please precise a piece of real data you retrieve, then we can see how to build dynamically the array you wish ;)